# trying to write a contract for Hotel menu in solidity, and try to map order and table number

Tags: solidity

I am new to programming, can any one help me to understand how to map the order number and the table number in a hotel contact, i tryed up to map both order and table but not able to get the proper linkage for both and out put as order 2 table number 1.

and adding items to a particular order as order1"item 1- Dosa, Qty2, item-2 idly Qty 1"

below is my source code.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Menu{
    uint256 public BookingId;
    address public Guest;
    uint256 Qty;
    
    struct Menuitem{
        uint256  id;
        string name;
        uint256 Price;
    }
    struct table{
        uint256 tableid;
        uint256 numberofseats;
    }
      mapping (uint256 => Menuitem) public Order;
      mapping (uint256  =>mapping(uint256 => Menuitem)) public tableno;
      Menuitem[] itemarray;
      table[5] tablearray;
     
      
      function welcome() public {
          log0("welcome");   /*need to ask*/
      }
      
      function additem(uint256 _id, string memory _name, uint256 _price) public{
          
        Menuitem memory newitem = Menuitem(_id, _name, _price);
        Order[_id] = newitem;
        itemarray.push(newitem);
        Qty++;
      }
      function itemcount() public view returns(uint256){
          return Qty;
      }
      function deleteitem(uint256 _id) public{
          delete Order[_id];
          Qty--;
      }
     
      
      function getItem(uint256 _id) view public returns (string memory _name, uint256 _price) {   
         return(Order[_id].name, Order[_id].Price);
    }
}
```

I have created a source code for menu contract, but not able to create order with more than the one 1 item

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;


contract HotelMenu{
    
                   struct Menu{
                                uint256 ID;
                                string Name;
                                uint256 Price;
                             }
                    uint256 ItemID;
                    mapping (uint256 => Menu) public Menuitems;
                    Menu[] public itemarray;
                    
                    struct Order{
                                   //uint256 OrderId;
                                   uint256 ItemID;
                                   uint256 Qty;
                                }
                    uint256 NextOrder;
                    mapping (uint256 => Order) public Orders;
                    Order[] public orderarray;
                    
                    event NewOrder (
                                        uint256 indexed ItemID,
                                        uint256 indexed OrderId
                                    );
                                       
                    function additemtomenu(string memory name, uint256 price) public
                                        {
                                        itemarray.push(Menu (ItemID, name, price));
                                        ItemID++;
                                        }
                    function PlaceOrder(uint256 _ItemID, uint256 Qty) public
                     {
                           //bookings[bookingId] = Booking(_propertyId, checkInDate, checkoutDate, msg.sender);
                           Orders[NextOrder] = Order(_ItemID, Qty);
                           //Property storage property = properties[_propertyId];
                           
                           emit NewOrder(_ItemID, NextOrder++);
                     }  
                     
                    function GetOrder(uint256 OrderId) public returns(uint256 , uint256)
                     {
                         for (uint256 i=0;i<=orderarray.length;i++)
                         {
                             if(orderarray[i].ItemID == OrderId)
                             {
                                return (orderarray[i].ItemID, orderarray[i].Qty); 
                             }
                         }
                         
                     }
                     
    
}
```

Regards,
Naresh

Comment: It is not clear what do you want to achieve. Can you add more details? Also the code assign `newitem` to a mapping and an array creating two unrelated copies, that is a bug unless you really want two copies.

Comment: HI, thanks for taking time for go thru, basically i am trying to write a code for a hotel by using mapping to menu, order and the table to reserve. and when i try to write a code i can able to push an item to menu by taking new item as Variable but i am not able to create a order by taking the items from same menu, of-course the code is incomplete.

Comment: We can help you with the solidity part, but we can't solve for you the relationship of menu, order and table. How these are related? What do you expect to be able to do? Edit your question to add examples of menu, order and table.

Comment: example: i have 50 items in menu(struct for menu create), from menu i can take 2 items(mapping with menu and order with item ID and qty) once ordered we will get the order number, for the particular order number need a table to be reserved or served, so the order taking and serving need to know the details of order and bill will be supplier to that particular ordered table .

Comment: Hi Ismael, i have modified the if you can share your mail id,  i will send code.

Comment: I'll suggest to first try solving the same problem in another laguage you are more familiar like python, java, etc. Solidity imposes restrictions that are tough to get over if you are not accostumed to it. Once you have a solution then translating to solidity is straightforward.